# How to draw image on current lat log in every 1 km via aidl?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw lat log in every 1 Km interval using service.
I have been got lat log in every 1 km but I want to draw image on that.

I am creating a function to get location via service(aidl file) and draw image on lat log in my activity.

In this service locationChange method change lat log in every 1 Km but its aidl method return value once to activity but I want that it return value to activity in every 1 Km.

How can I achieve this and also tell when phone is lock or any call coming then, 
 how to draw image on particular lat log in application in background.

I want like this 
 [example](http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/243.html)

Any idea and link please share and tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [code](https://github.com/marcfasel/LocationMapper/blob/master/src/com/shinetech/android/LocationListenerService.java)

it helps you to update current location using Service